# How can I disable the automatic selection of input text on Save To fields (and similar) when switching between windows on Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, ms-office

When I'm typing a file name on any Microsoft Office application on Windows 10 and switch to another window before hitting "Save" using Alt + Tab (for example, to copy a piece of text that will be the name of the file), whatever I've written so far gets automatically selected (in blue) when I go back to the Office app with the Save To window open.

This is undesirable most of the times because it can lead to inadvertently overwriting what was already written if the user continues to type without deselecting the text that was automatically selected.

Is there any way to disable this action?

[image: Before switching]

[image: Back on the Office app]

Comment: Fairly sure this happens in all Windows open/save dialogs. It's just Windows functionality. Not sure what you _could_ even use to disable that. Anyway... this is off topic; it is not at all a programming related question.

Comment: Subclass the window and remove the `DLGC_HASSETSEL` flag from the `WM_GETDLGCODE` message result. You'll have to get code into each process you want to do this to. For Word, this probably means writing a Word plug-in.